# StatefulJControllerMVCBinder Frozen class(cannot edit) error while adding new dependency

Tags: java, maven, exception

I'm trying to create "Dynamic Web Project" that uses "StatefulJ" framework(http://www.statefulj.org/). After adding dependency "statefulj-framework-binders-springmvc" I'm getting an error:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Unable to create bean; nested exception is org.apache.commons.lang3.NotImplementedException: Memory persister does not support usage of the FSMHarness
at org.statefulj.framework.core.StatefulFactory.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(StatefulFactory.java:321)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:119)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.lang3.NotImplementedException: Memory persister does not support usage of the FSMHarness
at org.statefulj.framework.core.model.impl.MemoryPersistenceSupportBeanFactoryImpl.buildFSMHarnessBean(MemoryPersistenceSupportBeanFactoryImpl.java:111)
at org.statefulj.framework.core.StatefulFactory.registerFSMHarness(StatefulFactory.java:1090)
at org.statefulj.framework.core.StatefulFactory.buildFramework(StatefulFactory.java:653)
at org.statefulj.framework.core.StatefulFactory.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(StatefulFactory.java:311)
... 22 more

paź 16, 2015 11:08:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [HelloWeb] in web application [/FMS] threw load() exception
org.apache.commons.lang3.NotImplementedException: Memory persister does not support usage of the FSMHarness
at org.statefulj.framework.core.model.impl.MemoryPersistenceSupportBeanFactoryImpl.buildFSMHarnessBean(MemoryPersistenceSupportBeanFactoryImpl.java:111)
at org.statefulj.framework.core.StatefulFactory.registerFSMHarness(StatefulFactory.java:1090)
at org.statefulj.framework.core.StatefulFactory.buildFramework(StatefulFactory.java:653)
at org.statefulj.framework.core.StatefulFactory.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(StatefulFactory.java:311)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:119)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

paź 16, 2015 11:08:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
paź 16, 2015 11:08:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
paź 16, 2015 11:08:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5592 ms
paź 16, 2015 11:08:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'HelloWeb'
paź 16, 2015 11:08:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Unable to create bean; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: statefulj.StatefulJControllerMVCBinder: frozen class (cannot edit)
at org.statefulj.framework.core.StatefulFactory.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(StatefulFactory.java:321)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:119)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: statefulj.StatefulJControllerMVCBinder: frozen class (cannot edit)
at javassist.ClassPool.checkNotFrozen(ClassPool.java:616)
at javassist.ClassPool.makeClass(ClassPool.java:810)
at javassist.ClassPool.makeClass(ClassPool.java:787)
at org.statefulj.framework.binders.common.AbstractRestfulBinder.buildProxy(AbstractRestfulBinder.java:119)
at org.statefulj.framework.binders.springmvc.SpringMVCBinder.buildProxy(SpringMVCBinder.java:93)
at org.statefulj.framework.binders.common.AbstractRestfulBinder.bindEndpoints(AbstractRestfulBinder.java:95)
at org.statefulj.framework.core.StatefulFactory.buildFramework(StatefulFactory.java:520)
at org.statefulj.framework.core.StatefulFactory.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(StatefulFactory.java:311)
... 29 more

paź 16, 2015 11:08:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet HelloWeb
java.lang.RuntimeException: statefulj.StatefulJControllerMVCBinder: frozen class (cannot edit)
at javassist.ClassPool.checkNotFrozen(ClassPool.java:616)
at javassist.ClassPool.makeClass(ClassPool.java:810)
at javassist.ClassPool.makeClass(ClassPool.java:787)
at org.statefulj.framework.binders.common.AbstractRestfulBinder.buildProxy(AbstractRestfulBinder.java:119)
at org.statefulj.framework.binders.springmvc.SpringMVCBinder.buildProxy(SpringMVCBinder.java:93)
at org.statefulj.framework.binders.common.AbstractRestfulBinder.bindEndpoints(AbstractRestfulBinder.java:95)
at org.statefulj.framework.core.StatefulFactory.buildFramework(StatefulFactory.java:520)
at org.statefulj.framework.core.StatefulFactory.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(StatefulFactory.java:311)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:119)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>FMS</groupId>
<artifactId>FMS</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <statefulj.version>1.0.11</statefulj.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.statefulj.framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>statefulj-framework-persistence-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${statefulj.version}</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.statefulj.framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>statefulj-framework-binders-springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${statefulj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="controller, statefulj" />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="statefulJFactory" class="org.statefulj.framework.core.StatefulFactory" />
</beans>
```

Have you encountered that kind of problem? I have no idea how to resolve this.

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace?

Comment: I don't know what I did but now I have additional exception "NotImplementedException: Memory persister does not support usage of the FSMHarness" But the previous one is still beeing thrown

Comment: What is happening is that the Domain Class associated with the Controller doesn't have Spring Repository associated with it (or StatefulJ isn't able to determine it from the Bean Repository).  If that is the case, you should see something like the following in the logs:

`Unable to find Spring Data Repository for <class>, using an in-memory persister`

So, StatefulJ will just only modify the entity in memory - not directly in the database.  As such, StatefulJ can't "fetch" it from the db, that is why you see " Memory persister does not support usage of the FSMHarness"

Comment: You are right. I added all repositories according to the demo application and it works :) Thank you(I can't vote your answer yet because I'm new)